# Nested form gem works for add, but does not work for delete in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using nested form gem with rails 4. link_to_add works perfectly. link_to_remove does not work. It removes the new nested form from the dom, but it does not actually delete the object. My model is campaign and my nested form is coming from a model named accessory.

**Campaign.rb**

```
has_many :accessories, :dependent => :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :accessories, :reject_if => :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
```

**Accessory.rb**

```
belongs_to :campaign
```

**Campaigns_controller.rb**

```
params.require(:campaign).permit(:product_name, :product_description, :accessories_attributes => [ :id, :name, :description, :_destroy ])
```

**Application.js**

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require tinymce
//= require jquery_nested_form
//= require cosmo/bootswatch
//= require_self
```

**new.html.erb**

```
<%= nested_form_for @campaign, :multipart => true do |f| %>

  <%= f.text_field :name %>

  <%= render 'campaigns/accessories_fields', :f => f %>
  <%= f.link_to_add "Add a accessory", :accessories %>

<% end %>
```

**_accessories_fields.html.erb**

```
<%= f.fields_for :accessories do |i| %>
   <%= i.text_field :name %>
   <%= i.link_to_remove "Remove this accessory" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Do you get any error ?

Comment: No, there is no errors in the log or console

Comment: Can you please share logs when you submit form

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned [here](https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form) you need to add

```
//= require jquery_nested_form
```

to your application.js file

Comment: I have now added require jquery_nested_form and result is the same.

Comment: Can you share the params[:campaign][:accessories_attributes] recieved on your controller when you delete a nested record?

Comment: Any Update on your query?

Comment: I thought the point of using the gem was so I didn't have to worry about what I do with the accessories in the delete method of my controller. I'm still messing with it, but I might just drop the gem.

Comment: If you are dropping the gem i would suggest you to use the gem called cocoon. Its pretty good